# Keep elements fixed, next to a transforming element

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

How can i make an element that i transform its width and height not affect its surrounding elements ?

```css
p {
    position: relative;
}
.p1 {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    border:1px solid blue;
    outline: 1px solid green;
    display:inline;
    text-align:center;
    background-color: red;
    color: #FFF;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    -webkit-transition: width 2s, height 2s, background-color 2s, -webkit-transform 2s, color 2s;
}
.p1:hover {
    width:500px;
    height: 500px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    color:black;
}
```

```html
<p class="p1">hello1</p>
<p style="" class="p1">hello2</p>
<p style="" class="p1">hello3</p>
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/toadalskii/mLx0x56n/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not scale it by changing the width/height since those affect the document flow.

Use the `scale` transform (*from 200 to 500 it is a scale of 2.5*) so use `transform: scale(2.5) rotate(180deg);`

```css
body {
    width:100%;
}
p {
    position: relative;
}
.p1 {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    border:1px solid blue;
    outline: 1px solid green;
    display:inline;
    text-align:center;
    background-color: red;
    color: #FFF;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    
    -webkit-transition: background-color 2s, -webkit-transform 2s, color 2s;
    transition: background-color 2s, transform 2s, color 2s;
}
.p1:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(2.5) rotate(180deg);
    transform: scale(2.5) rotate(180deg);
    color:black;
    z-index:100;
}
```

```html
<p class="p1">hello1</p>
<p class="p1">hello2</p>
<p class="p1">hello3</p>
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/mLx0x56n/1/